# Can't run SpriteKit project after install Xcode 6.3

Tags: xcode6, sprite-kit

I have just installed Xcode 6.3; I opened my project which I was working on in Xcode 6.2 Beta and got this error.

I don't know why; the project already runs successfully on Xcode 6.2

The screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j9ul.png

Answer (score 0):

childNodeWithName returns an optional SKNode (which makes sense as such a node may not exist) so you need to unwrap it before casting it to an SKspriteNode.

Why it worked in the beta I can't comment on.